# Flutter: View of message sent on whatsapp?

Tags: flutter, whatsapp

I want to get this message view, but I can't add clock and blue tick at the end. It should not look distorted when the message gets longer.

[image]

I tried such a code but the result was not the same.

```
Row sentMessage(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Container(
          child: Container(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
              maxWidth: displayWidth(context) * 0.80,
              minWidth: displayWidth(context) * 0.20,
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xffDCF8C6),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(9))),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: Text(messages[index]),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Text('11:11'),
                )
              ],
            ),
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: displayWidth(context) * 0.02,
              vertical: displayWidth(context) * 0.004,
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(displayWidth(context) * 0.02),
          ),
          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
          width: displayWidth(context),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

This is the result

[image]

Comment: @gmdev The question seems simple, but it is truly a confusing situation.I'm just doing this for learning.If someone wants to encode whatsapp to learn, I'm sure he'll get stuck in this part like me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to do it myself after spending some time and thinking.

```
Row sentMessage(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Container(
          child: Container(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
              maxWidth: displayWidth(context) * 0.80,
              minWidth: displayWidth(context) * 0.20,
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xffDCF8C6),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))),
            child: Wrap(
              verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.down,
              alignment: WrapAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      bottom: displayHeightOutAppBar(context) * 0.005),
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(
                    maxWidth: displayWidth(context) * 0.80,
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    messages[index],
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: displayWidth(context) * 0.04,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: displayHeightOutAppBar(context) * 0.006,
                      left: displayWidth(context) * 0.015),
                  //alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(
                    maxWidth: displayWidth(context) * 0.20,
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    '11:11',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: displayHeightOutAppBar(context) * 0.006),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.done_all,
                    size: displayWidth(context) * 0.04,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: displayWidth(context) * 0.02,
              vertical: displayWidth(context) * 0.004,
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: displayWidth(context) * 0.015,
                right: displayWidth(context) * 0.015,
                top: displayWidth(context) * 0.015),
          ),
          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
          width: displayWidth(context),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

[image]

**I add an explanation with the recommendation of @gmdev**

The wrong thing I did was to place the items one on the other using the "Column".Instead I placed them side by side using "Wrap".
I gave "MaxWidth" value to "Containers" that cover the items inside instead of the main "Container".I adjusted the spaces between them with "Padding" and "Margin".

Maybe there are different ways to do this but I think it's the simplest way.Those with different solutions can write

**Here I froze again and added the second edit**

There is a small triangle on the edge of the first message sent via Whatsapp.The only way to do this is "ClipPath".If your math is not good, you will have to work hard to do this.Couldn't find a similar example on the internet.

[image]

```
Row firstSentMessage(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Container(
          child: ClipPath(
            clipper: MyCustomClipper1(),
            child: Container(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                maxWidth: displayWidth(context) * 0.80,
                minWidth: displayWidth(context) * 0.20,
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xffDCF8C6),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(5),
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(5),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(5)),
              ),
              child: Wrap(
                verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.down,
                alignment: WrapAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        bottom: displayHeightOutAppBar(context) * 0.005),
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(
                      maxWidth: displayWidth(context) * 0.80,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      messages[index],
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: displayWidth(context) * 0.04,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: displayHeightOutAppBar(context) * 0.006,
                      left: displayWidth(context) * 0.015,
                    ),
                    //alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(
                      maxWidth: displayWidth(context) * 0.20,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      '11:11',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: displayHeightOutAppBar(context) * 0.006,
                      right: displayWidth(context) * 0.015,
                    ),
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.done_all,
                      size: displayWidth(context) * 0.04,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: displayWidth(context) * 0.01,
                vertical: displayWidth(context) * 0.004,
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: displayWidth(context) * 0.015,
                  right: displayWidth(context) * 0.015,
                  top: displayWidth(context) * 0.015),
            ),
          ),
          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
          width: displayWidth(context),
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: displayHeightOutAppBar(context) * 0.007),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

And this is "Clipper".

```
class MyCustomClipper1 extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();

    path.lineTo(0, size.height);
    path.lineTo(20, size.height);
    path.arcToPoint(Offset(size.width - 12, 13),
        radius: Radius.circular(1), clockwise: false);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);

    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}
```

I added "ClipPath" and "clipper" for it in new codes.I slightly changed the "padding" and "margin" values to make the image correct.

Comment: It's great that you came back and answered your own question. Might you add a brief explanation on what you changed to make it work? So that future users will *understand* why it works :)

Comment: @gmdev Thanks for coming back here and caring.I added a description, I hope it will be enough

Comment: Perfect, don't forget to accept your answer when your'e able to :)

Answer (score 3):

**My Code  :**

```
[import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OwnMessageCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const OwnMessageCard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
          maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 45,
        ),
        child: Card(
          elevation: 1,
          shape:
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
          color: Color(0xffdcf8c6),
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 15,
            vertical: 5,
          ),
          child: Stack(children: \[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 10,
                right: 60,
                top: 10,
                bottom: 20,
              ),
              child: Text(
                "Hey, Joy Sinha",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 4,
              right: 10,
              child: Row(
                children: \[
                  Text(
                    "20:58",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 13,
                      color: Colors.grey\[600\],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 5,
                  ),
                  Icon(
                    Icons.done_all,
                    size: 20,
                  ),
                \],
              ),
            ),
          \]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}][1]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and explain what this code does, for more clarification. Read [answer] and take the [tour] to learn how this site works.